# malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, mergesort

Below is function to do merge sort. but I meet error when I execute. The allocated memory(aux) has been freed every time in function `merge`, why it will be modified after freed?

> ```
> a.out(65287,0x1112bedc0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object
> 0x7ff9a4c05888: probably modified after being freed. Corrupt value:
> 0xb00000003 a.out(65287,0x1112bedc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in
> malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6
> ```

```
void merge(int arr[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int i = lo; 
    int j = mid + 1;
    int *aux = (int *)malloc((hi - lo + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        aux[k] = arr[k];
    }   
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        if (i > mid)
            arr[k] = aux[j++];
        else if (j > hi)
            arr[k] = aux[i++];
        else if (aux[i] > aux[j])
            arr[k] = aux[j++];
        else
            arr[k] = aux[i++];
    } 
    free(aux);
}

void mergesort1(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi)
        return;
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    mergesort1(arr, lo, mid);
    mergesort1(arr, mid + 1, hi);
    merge(arr, lo, mid, hi);
}
```

call with:

```
mergesort1(arr, 0, 9);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc((hi - lo + 1) * sizeof(int))` allocates space for elements indexed from 0 to `hi-lo`, but `for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) … aux[k] = …` accesses the elements with indices from `lo` to `hi`, thus writing outside the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `aux` array is not initialized properly: `for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) { aux[k] = arr[k]; }` should be:

```
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        aux[k -lo] = arr[k];
    }
```

Your code writes beyond the end of the allocated array, potentially causing corruption of the data used by `malloc()` and `free()` to keep track of allocated memory.

Note that `i` and `j` should also be initialized differently and it is confusing to include the upper bound in the merge sort algorithm. If `hi` is excluded, the code is simpler as no `+1`/`-1` adjustments are necessary:

```c
void merge1(int arr[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int i = 0; 
    int j = mid -= lo;
    int n = hi - lo;
    int *aux = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        aux[k] = arr[lo + k];
    }   
    for (int k = lo; k < hi; k++) {
        if (i >= mid)
            arr[k] = aux[j++];
        else if (j >= n)
            arr[k] = aux[i++];
        else if (aux[i] > aux[j])
            arr[k] = aux[j++];
        else
            arr[k] = aux[i++];
    } 
    free(aux);
}

void mergesort1(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi - lo < 2)
        return;
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    mergesort1(arr, lo, mid);
    mergesort1(arr, mid, hi);
    merge1(arr, lo, mid, hi);
}
```

call with: `mergesort1(arr, 0, 10);`, which is simpler because 10 is the array length.

The code can be further simplified using pointer arithmetic:

```c
void merge2(int arr[], int mid, int hi) {
    int *aux = malloc(n * sizeof(*aux));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        aux[i] = arr[i];
    }   
    for (int i = 0, j = mid, k = 0; i < mid;) {
        if (j >= n || aux[i] <= aux[j])
            arr[k++] = aux[i++];
        else
            arr[k++] = aux[j++];
    } 
    free(aux);
}

void mergesort2(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int mid = n / 2;
    mergesort2(arr, mid);
    mergesort2(arr + mid, n - mid);
    merge2(arr, mid, n);
}
```

call with: `mergesort2(arr, 10);`, where 10 is the array length.